# How to change the sort icon in agGrid like angle arrow icon in fontawesome icons in angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: '',
    field: 'id',
    maxWidth: 50,
    cellRenderer: 'selectRenderer'
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Project Code',
    field: 'projectCode',
    minWidth: 75,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Project/Sub-Project Name',
    field: 'projectName',
    minWidth: 300,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Start Date',
    field: 'startDate',
    minWidth: 100,
    sortable: true
  },
  { headerName: 'End Date', field: 'endDate', minWidth: 95 },
  {
    headerName: 'Current Budget',
    field: 'currentBudget',
    minWidth: 130,
    cellRenderer: function(param) {
      return `${param.data.currentBudget} USD`;
    }
  },
  { headerName: '', field: '', cellRenderer: 'editRenderer', maxWidth: 100 }
];
```

This is my column definition for the table. I have used sortable as true in neccassary columns. I need to change the default icon type of sort in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the icons property of the column definition to set a custom icon for sort on a column level or icons property of gridOptions to apply for all columns. If defined in both the grid options and column definitions, the column definition will get used.

```
  this.icons = {
    sortAscending: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-down "/>',
    sortDescending: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"/>',
  };
```

Add `[icons]="icons"` in the template inside the `ag-grid-angular` tag like so

```
  <ag-grid-angular
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [icons]="icons"
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Also you must import fontawesome css file for this to work.

Check this link for documentation - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-icons/

Comment: What about for React. This documentation is also really confusing, all I want to do is show a icon in one of the headers, shouldn't be this complicated.

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar my guess is you already got the answer, if not, you can refer to [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/custom-icons/#example) for react. Here you can see the `Athlete` column is having some different icon whereas `Age` column is having a different one